# I see this code to be vulnerable. What might be the cause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-injection

```
if (isset($_POST['Login'])){

$UserName=$_POST['UserName'];
$Password=$_POST['Password'];

$login_query=mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"],"select * from voters where Username='$UserName' and Password='$Password' and Status='Unvoted' and Year='1st year'") or die(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using [Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), rather that catenating results from your input directly. Otherwise you're vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

Anytime that you're using the variable that a user submitted and don't protect against it, you're vulnerable.

As rogue said, you can use Prepared statements, or use some version of quoting, such as pdo's:

```
$password = $db->quote($password);
```

Comment: thnks. would be glad if you convert the above code to pdo

Comment: `mysqli_query` does not allow multiple statements. So your example is wrong.

Comment: @Gumbo Interesting - you are definitely correct. I've used PDO much more than mysqli, so I was unaware of this.

Comment: @YourCommonSense At least you're the paragon of perfection we all strive for. In case you are as illiterate as you are judgmental, what ACTUALLY happened is that my example was incorrect - the answer itself is still valid.